# Real-time recommendation engine data models in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, recommendation-engine

My query is:

Given a user id, find the appropriate song recommendation for this user based on their ratings compared against other users' ratings.

I want everything to be real time here.  So, as events come in, weight the recommendations appropriately and maintain a column family that supports a query like

`SELECT recommendation_id FROM cf WHERE user_id=123 AND recommendation_type='song'`

so, I was thinking something like a column family that stores all the ratings of a user (each song is a column), and then a set of recommendations.  However, I can't come up with a way to make this work in real-time.  I want a storm topology that populates the rating as well as the possible recommendations.

Another thing that seems messy about this is that it requires a lot of updating in cassandra.  It would be better if it were only creating, right?

I've been trying to find examples of such a data model, and have yet to find one.  Any resources others have found would be helpful.

**Update:**  Another way to frame the problem, is that I'm trying to find a data structure that supports iterative collaborative filtering.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently seen these slides from Spotify about using [ML + Hadoop for Predictive analysis](http://www.slideshare.net/erikbern/mlhadoop-nyc-predictive-analytics-2) using matrix factorization. As you'll see in the slide 11 Cassandra is in the picture, but most of the results are precomputed every night.

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this answer, I wanted to add just a bit.  Basically, I don't think this is a solved problem yet.  Collaborative filtering needs to compare all users against one another, and as far as I can find, there isn't a way to do it iteratively (as in, without looking at every user at run time).  The best you could do is probably spark (suggested in the slideshare)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the CQL collections including sets, maps and lists. Have a look at this blog post by the Datastax community :

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections